# Read XML Element based on previous element

Tags: c#, xml, soap

Good day.
im hoping that somebody could please assist me. i have spent days trying to figure this out without much luck. i have an XML SOAP document which i am trying to get certain values from. below is a snipped of the document.

```
<Devices isOnline="false">
        <deviceId>
          <Number>1</Number>
          <Id>11111</Id>
        </deviceId>
        <lastUploadDateTime>2017-07-27</lastUploadDateTime>
        <Parameters>
          <TempId>22222</TempId>
          <MappedId>3333</MappedId>
        </Parameters>
 </Devices>
```

i need to first search for in the deviceID to check for a specific ID, if i find a match i then need to go to the pararameters and get the values of the TempID and MappedID elements.

so far i have the following code which loops through the Devices element, but i am unsure of how to check for a specific ID under deviceId and then get the values of TempId and MappedId under Parameters.

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
 XNamespace ns = "http://";
 IEnumerable<XElement> responses = doc.Descendants("Devices");


 foreach (XElement response in responses)
 {

 }
```

Any Assistance would be greatly appreciated. i have tried many examples i have found, but none that are able to get my exact details i require.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many ways to traverse your xml.

one way is as follows:

```
foreach (XElement response in responses)
{
    var tempIdElement = 
    response.Descendants("Parameters").Elements("TempId").FirstOrDefault();

    string value = tempIdElement.Value;
}
```

when you call `.Descendants()`, it would give you all the child elements under this. So, in the above code, we get the `Parameters` and under the parameters, we find the `TempId`.

As you experiment with Linq, you can find different ways of achieving this result.

You should also add necessary null condition checks to handle the scenario of missing elements in the Xml.

Comment: Thank you so much Pastør and Bruno.
you have helped me tremendously. i really appreciate the time you have taken to help me with this. it is no working as expected.

Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

firstable I would declare a class for this entity and then query the XML:

```
public class DevicesParam
{
    public DevicesParam() { }

    public long TempId { get; set; }
    public long MappedId { get; set; }
}
```

And then write a LINQ to XML query like this:

```
var parameters = (from p in responses.Descendants("Parameters") select new 
DevicesParam {                                                                    
    TempId = p.TempId ?? 0 ,                                                                                  
    MappedId = p.MappedId ?? 0                                                                                    
}).SingleOrDefault();
```

Here you have a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) for reading more about LINQ to XML in C#